sshd refuses to verify SSH keys, postponing a key despite accepting it, because Bitdefender seems to intercept it, which ultimately prevents login
After fighting trying to login to this server without a password for a while, regenerating host keys, restarting sshd, and more, it turns out to be Bitdefender Security Tools Daemon's fault, as restarting its services by the means of systemctl restart bdsec.service bdsec-daemon.service bdsec-epagng.service bdsec-update.service suddenly made logging in work... for a while.
client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0: incorrect signature

/root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: matching key found: ED25519 SHA256:<HASH>
mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: ED25519 key is allowed
crypto_sign_ed25519_open failed: -1
mm_answer_keyverify: publickey ED25519 signature using ssh-ed25519 unverified: incorrect signature


mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication: RSA key is allowed
mm_answer_keyverify: publickey RSA signature using rsa-sha2-512 unverified: incorrect signature

All passes except the final OpenSSL check, this is stock with sshd_config, both RSA and ED25519 keys fail.
I am not sure how to convince Bitdefender to stop interfering with SSH.
This is on a fully up to date Ubuntu 22.04 - OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

https://www.bitdefender.com/business/support/en/77209-343039-nad--ssh-pki-authentication-on-endpoint-outbound-connections.html
Turns out that Bitdefender can be configured to use an SSH proxy with its own keys to connect to the endpoint that was requested, even if that was a forwarded SSH port, so it's trying to remotely connect to localhost...
This can be verified by running systemctl restart bdsec-daemon and immediately trying to connect, which should work, until the daemon kicks in and hijacks the connection again.
First I replaced its host keys with that of OpenSSH to prevent key mismatch:
rsync -av /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa* /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519* /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa* /opt/bitdefender-security-tools/etc/ssh/
chown root:bitdefender /opt/bitdefender-security-tools/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
chmod 600 /opt/bitdefender-security-tools/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*

Then I needed to create /opt/bitdefender-security-tools/etc/ssh/keys-root with authorized_keys reflecting the server's, a new id_ed25519 and id_ed25519.pub and added that one to the server's authorized keys, to allow for the genius doubled connection to localhost to occur.
mkdir /opt/bitdefender-security-tools/etc/ssh/keys-root
# Save under /opt/bitdefender-security-tools/etc/ssh/keys-root
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /opt/bitdefender-security-tools/etc/ssh/keys-root
chown -R root:bitdefender /opt/bitdefender-security-tools/etc/ssh/keys-root
cat /opt/bitdefender-security-tools/etc/ssh/keys-root/id_ed25519.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

After this circus performance, I could actually login through the AutoSSH forwarded port.
